# improper integral convergence/divergence

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I need to determine whether the improper integral, $\int ^{\infty }_{1}(1-\cos \left( \dfrac{1}{x}\right)) dx$ converges or diverges.
Now, I only need to decide if it converges or diverges by comparison tests, I don't need to try to calculate it's value, if converges.
There isn't a comparison test that comes up to my mind to use in this question (Dirichlet test isn't working here, I tried).
From intergration by substitution I converted the integral to $\int ^{1}_{0}\dfrac{1-\cos \left( t\right) }{t^{2}}dt$ but it didn't lead to any result.
If someone can help I'll be glad.

Comment: No result?! What's wrong with $\int ^{1}_{0}\dfrac{1-\cos \left( t\right) }{t^{2}}dt$? The integrand is continuous and bounded in $(0,1)$, what else do you need?

Comment: the integrand is not defined on $[0, 1]$ so how can you use this?

Comment: I was talking about $(0,1)$, and that's enough to define the value of this integral.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}(|b|-|a|)$

Answer (score 1):

Since the power series expansion of cosine converges for all real $x$, one can see that both these integrals converge by integrating their power series expansions.

For the second expression, there can only be a problem at $t=0$ but the series expansion shows $\cos (t) = 1 - \frac{t^2}{2} + O(t^4)$.
Thus, the function is bounded in the neighborhood of $t=0$.